# IoT hub azure - ble device and pwa application

Tags: bluetooth, progressive-web-apps, iot, azure-iot-hub

I have an **IOT device** which communicates through **bluetooth** with my PWA (Vue js) application.

Can the **telemetrics** be sent to IOT azure hub?

IOT hub is not very clear to me. Do I have to create a server which communicates with the PWA? (ble <-> PWA -> backend -> IOT hub)

```js
var Mqtt = require('azure-iot-device-mqtt').Mqtt;
var DeviceClient = require('azure-iot-device').Client
var Message = require('azure-iot-device').Message;

var client = DeviceClient.fromConnectionString(connectionString, Mqtt);

// Create a message and send it to the IoT hub every second
setInterval(function(){
  // Simulate telemetry.
  var temperature = 20 + (Math.random() * 15);
  var message = new Message(JSON.stringify({
    temperature: temperature,
    humidity: 60 + (Math.random() * 20)
  }));

  // Add a custom application property to the message.
  // An IoT hub can filter on these properties without access to the message body.
  message.properties.add('temperatureAlert', (temperature > 30) ? 'true' : 'false');

  console.log('Sending message: ' + message.getData());

  // Send the message.
  client.sendEvent(message, function (err) {
    if (err) {
      console.error('send error: ' + err.toString());
    } else {
      console.log('message sent');
    }
  });
}, 10000);
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not necessary to create a backend server to communicate with the PWA. Actually, you can use MQTT over Web Sockets protocol to establish the communication in vue js application. Please refer to this doucment:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-mqtt-support

Comment: Yes, I tried like this, but it can't get the websocket conenction, I receive: UnauthorizedError: mqtt.js returned mqtt.js returned Failure on first connection (Not authorized): Unable to establish a connection error error. 
But it works on node.js.

Comment: I added in the description.

Comment: I have tried to test the connection with mqtt over websocket, it fails with error 'WebSocket connection to 'ws://{iot-hostname}/mqtt' failed: Connection closed before receiving a handshake response'. When i use http protocol, it will connect successfully, but the app can not send the message because of cross cors issue.I think we need to config the app to allow cors request.

Comment: I also found this: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1113447/Azure-IOT-Hub-REST-API